# Avoiding References to Other Assemblies When Using Child Classes of Generic Base Classes

Tags: .net, generics, inheritance

Let’s suppose I have an hypothetical  application with 3 layers (assemblies): `Data`, `Biz`, and `Gui`.
My Biz assembly has a generic base class that nearly every other Biz class inherits from:

```
namespace Biz
{
   // Base Class
   public abstract class BizBase<T>
   {
      public string GetDataName()
      {
         return typeof(T).Name;
      }

      abstract internal protected T GetDataObject();
   }

   // Child Class
   public class Foo: BizBase<Data.Bar>
   {
       override internal protected Data.Bar GetDataObject()
       {
          Data.Bar ret = null;
          ... //Do stuff
          return ret;
       }
   }
}
```

Obviously this is a very simple example, but lets assume there is a lot of logic in `BizBase` that is reliant on `GetDataObect()` and that the Gui uses Biz objects directly.

```
namespace Gui
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)         
    {
        Biz.Foo foo = new Biz.Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.GetDataName);    
    }
}
```

**The Issue**:

I want my `Biz` assembly to have a reference to my `Data` assembly, and I want my `Gui` to have a reference to `Biz`, but I do not want my "Gui" assembly to have a reference to my "Data" assembly. Unfortunately, I get compile-time errors if I do not include a reference to `Data` in `Gui`.

**So My Questions Are**

1. Why does `Gui` need a reference to `Data`? `GetDataObject()` is internal, so I don't see why reference is needed in order to compile.
2. How do I avoid having my "Gui" assembly need a reference to "Data"?

**Clarification**:

- The `Gui` layer is exactly what you think it is. In my case WPF, but it could just as easily be the Main method of a Console app.
- The `Data` classes are actually just Entities (POCOs generated using EF in my case). The actual DbContext is in a separate assembly that is not directly referenced (except where it is being registered with my IoC container using `IModule`s).
- The `Biz` classes mostly store the bulk of my business and validation logic and each map to a single `Data` class (`Biz.Color` inherits from `Biz.BizBase<Data.Color>`). The Biz classes use an `IDataStore` service (which is the Dependency-Injected DbContext) to retrieve/save the specific Data objects that they use.

Originally, I had a non-generic BizBase class, but I found that I was duplicating a lot of CRUD logic in each Biz class where they were interacting with the IDataStore and the specific entity type they used. BizBase had several abstract methods that (save for the specific type of entity being used) was implemented identically in every child class.

I was able to move almost all of this logic the the base class by making it generic, but suddenly any consumer of my Biz classes needed a reference directly to my Data classes (my entities). And while my entities don't actually contain any logic for interacting with the database, I'm reluctant to just add a reference to them for anything that needs to use a Biz object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this type in your `Biz` layer:

```
public class Foo: BizBase<Data.Bar>
```

This is exposing your `Data` types (at least this one, but one is all you need) as *part* of your `Biz` types.  So anything which uses `Biz` is going to need a reference to `Data` just to understand what `Foo` is, because `Foo` carries an intrinsic dependency on `Data.Bar`.

In order to achieve the separation you're looking for, `Biz` shouldn't reference `Data` at all.  Which means it *definitely* shouldn't expose the types in `Data` publicly and therefore require all of its consumers to reference `Data`.

---

Your reference to the `Data` assembly is backwards.  References should point *inward* to the business logic, not *outward* from the business logic.  (See "The Dependency Rule" [in this article](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).)

The details are probably a bit broad for a Stack Overflow question, but essentially:

- `Data` should reference `Biz`
- `Gui` should reference `Biz`
- `Biz` should reference nothing.

Of course, then `Biz` needs a way to invoke operations in `Data`.  This is where dependency injection comes in.  If `Data` implements interfaces which are in `Biz` then `Biz` can code to those interfaces.  The dependency injector (which doesn't have to be a framework, but might as well be) would supply instances of the implementations for those interfaces where needed.

It's *kind of* the responsibility of the application layer to know which dependencies it needs, at least from an environment configuration point of view.  (Configuring the dependency injector in an `App.config`, for example.)  In simple enough applications, the dependency injection can be part of the application itself.  In these cases `Gui` *should* have a reference to `Data` because it needs to know which implementations to use for the interfaces.

But even in simple applications there is, as you indicate, a desire *not* to have `Gui` reference `Data`.  After all, at the very least that carries the risk of code in `Gui` invoking code directly in `Data`, which defeats the architecture.

Instead, consider a fourth layer which is orthogonal to the other three layers.  The `DI` layer.  What you'd have then is:

- `Biz` references nothing
- `Data` references `Biz`
- `DI` references `Biz` and `Data`
- `Gui` references `Biz` and `DI`

`Gui` would initialize the dependency injection in `DI` (usually on application startup for dependency injection frameworks), then use that system to get implementations based on interfaces.  At no point would `Gui` know (or care) what the implementations are.  It doesn't need a reference to those libraries.

The runtime output would still need those libraries in place, of course.  But code in `Gui` would never "see" (in any design-time or compile-time way) the dependencies (`Data`).  It would only initialize the `DI` and then conduct all logic through `Biz`, supplying it instances it gets from `DI`.

---

For some concrete examples of this architecture in .NET, take a look at a (somewhat old) [presentation I put together here](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/dependency-injection-screencast.html).  Code samples referenced in the presentation [are available here](https://github.com/dpdonahue/What-Is-Dependency-Injection-).  (Note: I really should update these examples to use Entity Framework.  Yes, it's that old.  I do have some simple code samples [in an article here](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/persistence-ignorance-with-entity.html) which demonstrates some of the same concepts applied to EF.)

Comment: I added some clarification about what each assembly is for. It would seem that (according to the article you posted anyway) the references are actually in the correct direction. But the actual application I am working on has more than 3 layers, and I would just rather not have my outer-most layers have references all the way to the inner-most layer if it could be avoided.  Especially since none of the properties/methods of any of my Biz objects publicly expose any Data objects.

Comment: @NuclearProgrammer: What assembly is this class in?:  `public class Foo: BizBase<Data.Bar>`  If that's in `Biz` then the references are clearly backwards and not following the article/examples I linked, because `Biz` would need to reference `Data` in order to use it as a type.  Which is also explaining the issue you're seeing because `Biz` is not only *referencing* `Data` (which it shouldn't), but it's *exposing* classes in `Data` as part of its *own* types.  This creates a hard dependency on `Data` everywhere in the system, which negates all the benefits of separation and injection.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the article. It has been very helpful, and has helped me identify a misunderstanding I've had. I've been thinking of Biz and Data as seperate layers when really they are both just part of my "Model" layer. The important thing here is that Data in my example doesn't actually rely on any framework. This is because my DbContext is actually in a completely seperate assembly (my "DataAccess" assembly which I had omitted from my original example in attempt to keep it simple) and serves as a repository for my Data objects (which are really just Models)